# How do I copy and paste from text cell to StackExchange to keep textbook formatted notation?

Tags: discussion, mathjax

I use Mathematica to create notebooks that include "text" cells only. I use them to create textbook formatted mathematical notation.

Occasionally I use the Stack Exchange Mathematics forum to ask math questions. I write up the problem using a text cell in Mathematica and then I take a screen shot to include in my StackExchange post. That way the notation looks as it would in a textbook. But a screenshot is not optimal. I have been told I should use MathJax to enter properly formatted expressions.

I do not want to learn MathJax. I would rather find a way to copy and paste directly from Mathematica? Is this possible? If not, is there a 1 or 2 or 3 step process for which I can copy and paste and then convert without having to learn how to code MathJax?

Comment: MathJax is a subset of LaTeX, so just right click on the cell edge and select "copy as" LaTeX.

Comment: @C.E. But that will create math-mode LaTeX even for non-math text.  And the generated LaTeX may need cleanup too.  So there's no way around learning at least the basics of math-mode LaTeX notation.  That should take no more than an 0.5-1 hour and it's well worth the time if you are going to do any amount of writing about math (including SE posts).

Comment: However, you can always choose to copy *only* the formula as TeX code from Mathematica, and type the rest of the text normally. Observe the TeX code and use it to learn to write it manually over time.

Comment: @Szabolcs I looked at [one of the posts](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1919009/2) and the Mathematica excerpts are just formulas, no text.

Comment: @Szabolcs.  The formulas were created in a text cell.  They are text cells with inline formulas.  I would like to copy the whole text cell which includes inline formulas like the ones I've posted.  I will take your advice and learn some Tex.

Comment: I just recalled that R.M. developed a solution for converting entire notebooks into StackExchange Markdown so they can be posted directly. The first download link I found right now is the comment of Jacob [here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/990/is-there-a-way-to-convert-a-mathematica-notebook-to-stack-exchange-format).

Comment: @C.E. I'm sorry, it seems I misunderstood.  A simple Copy as TeX should work then.  It's also a good starting point to learn basic math-mode TeX.